# Firebase Functions failing Run the latest Code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that runs based on a trigger to create a chat room. The function was running for a long time correctly until I updated it to add a new field on the document it is creating. That is **archived: false**.
After adding the field on the function, it sometimes adds the field when it runs but at times fails to add the field. So I think that firebase at times runs the updated code and sometimes runs the only code when the function is triggered because all other fields are created apart from the **archived: false** which is created and sometimes not created.
So I fail to understand why this happens yet in the code, the field archived is not dependent on any other variable.

Below is the function.

```js
// firestore trigger to crete a chat room
exports.createChatRooms = functions.firestore.document("/jobs/{id}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const job = change.after.data();

  if (job.status === "Accepted") {
    const roomId = context.params.id;

    const room = admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc(roomId);
    return room.set({
      name: job.title,
      jobId: roomId,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
      agent: job.agent,
      archived: false,
      user: job.user,
      members: [job.user.id, job.agent.id],

    });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Kindly help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: Is it happening in the actual production environment or are you using Firebase emulator? Also the function code is in typescript or javascript?

Comment: in the actual production
@Prabir

Comment: and the function is javascript

Comment: Can you update the code to add some log statement before the `return room.set()` statement and check the Functions log if it is always coming or not?